# How do I change a folder icon in OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

How to change the icon on a folder on your desktop. I was searching how to do this myself. I found the answer and posted it below.

Comment: This really belongs somewhere else, such as apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the image you want to use as the icon in Preview
2. Press 'Cmd' + 'A' to select the whole image Press 'Cmd' + 'C' to copy the image
3. Right click on the folder you would like to change the icon on
4. Select "Get Info" Click on the current icon in the top-right of this window
5. Press 'Cmd' + 'V' to paste and replace it

The icon should now be changed.